# What's the monomer in a polycarbonate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I know what the repeating unit is, but what's the monomer in a polycarbonate?

Comment: A polymer name is defined by the repeating unit. Polycarbonates (which is a large group of polymers) further are a nice example where the same repeating unit can be created in a number of ways, from different monomers.  Your question is a bit ambigous with regard to this. Please elaborate. *What* polycarbonate are we talking about?

Comment: Not all polymers are made of *single* monomers. Polycarbonates usually consist of at least 2 so asking what "the" monomer is isn't quite correct.

Answer (score 4):

Like [Dr J said](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/99475/5026) there is no single polycarbonate polymer, the most common one is formed from phosgene (or another carbon dioxide reagent) and bisphenol A. The repeating unit is $\ce{C6H4C(CH3)2C6H4-O-C(=O)-O -}$

In Nagahata, R.; Sugiyama, J.; Goyal, M.; Goto, M.; Asai, M.; Ueda, M.; Takeuchi, K. X-ray analysis of the bisphenol-A-type macrocyclic carbonate trimer. *Polym. Adv. Technol.* **2000,** *11* (6), 294–300. [DOI: 10.1002/1099-1581(200006)11:6<294::AID-PAT979>3.0.CO;2-C](https://doi.org/10.1002/1099-1581(200006)11:6%3C294::AID-PAT979%3E3.0.CO;2-C). (OCAMUA) a tetramer of the repeat unit of this polymer has been reported. This is a small cyclic polymer (oligomer).

Answer (score 3):

There is no one single answer to your question as posed. Polycarbonates (PC) are a group of polymers, the most common of which would probably be the polycarbonate of bisphenol A. The monomer of this PC can be seen here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycarbonate.  There are hundreds of other polycarbonate resins that exist, and they will each have their own unique structure and unique monomer.